# How to intercept form submission and change action with plain javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to intercept a form submission and change the action to a different URL before letting the submission proceed?
All kinds of form submission should be intercepted (user clicking on button, javascript call, whatever).

Edit:
all solutions using the onsubmit event aren't good because, as stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit), the event isn't triggered when calling submit():

> The form's onsubmit event handler (for example, onsubmit="return
>   false;") will not be triggered when invoking this method from
>   Gecko-based applications.

So for example

```
document.forms["myform"].submit()
```

won't trigger the event.

Comment: The only method that I know of would not intercept a javascript form-submission call (but would catch the user-initiated submission methods).

Comment: Before helping someone with script injection.. what would you need this for?

Comment: @DrunkWolf, you do realize this is a public site, so even if I gave you an "innocent" explanation, there might be a million other users with malicious intentions? Besides, I read somewhere that "obscurity" is not "security" i.e. it's not by hiding knowledge that the world becomes a safer place.

Comment: @xtian Yes i do, i just honestly found it difficult to find a use case for this that wasn't at least a bit shady. So the question was more out of interest then anything else. That said, there's a difference between hiding knowledge and going out of your way to provide it.

Comment: I'm writing a web proxy and I want all form submissions to go to my proxy instead of the original server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For handling user submission via the submit button, I have to intercept the onsubmit event as explained in other answers. I copy one here from psylogic:

```
<form onsubmit="changeAction(this);">
    ...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeAction(form) {
        form.action = "example.com";
    }
</script>
```

For handling javascript submission via the submit() method, I can override that method in the prototype, one way of doing it being the following:

```
HTMLFormElement.prototype.original = HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit;
HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit = function() {
    this.action = "example.com";
    this.original(arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the URL you use, you may run into a cross-origin issue (read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). It's a security measure that prevents a page on a certain domain to make requests to another domain. The way to prevent this is to set CORs policy on the server side, if you have access to it.

It's possible to use JSOP for GET requests, but not for POST or UPDATE/PUT, which is the case when submitting a form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function onSubmitAction(elem) {
  var test = document.getElementById('test');
  if (test.value === 'aaa') {
    elem.setAttribute('action', 'bc.php');
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="ac.php" onsubmit="onSubmitAction(this)">
  <input type="text" id="test">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: onsubmit is not triggered by document.forms["myform"].submit()

Comment: `myform` has to be the name of the `form`