# How to reformat form submit url that has GET method on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with datarangepicker. The value in the input is a string

```html
<form action="calculate" method="GET">

  <input type="text" name="date_interval" value="08/01/2019 - 07/02/2019" id="range">

  <input type="submit">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var range = document.getElementById('range').toString();
  var arrayDates = range.split("-").map(function(item) {
    return item.trim();
  });
  arrayDates = arrayDates.map(item => item.replace('/', '-'));

</script>
```

When I submit the url above becomes encded with weird chars as shown below

```
https://www.webiste.co/calculate?date_interval=08%2F01%2F2019+-+07%2F02%2F2019
```

I want it to be redirected to a url something like

```
https://www.webiste.co/calculate/date_interval/08-01-2019/07-02-2019
```

In this question I take the value from input value, I don't submit to standart url
How can I do this on the fly?

https://jsfiddle.net/tok63p5f/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to intercept form submission and change action with plain javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701004/how-to-intercept-form-submission-and-change-action-with-plain-javascript)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca It is no. I explained why in the question.

Comment: So your actual question is not how to intercept the submit event but how to manipulate the url to NOT pass the date as an actual GET parameter?

Comment: remove the space and slash like 08-01-2019-07-02-2019 now check.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca nope. Just giving steps. Step 1: Get input value of date_interval Step 2: Reformation this value by replacing '-' with / and replacing '/' with '-' Step 3: Change submit action url as shown above in the link. They are !0% similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must obtain the 2 dates, this could be a way:

```
let arrayDates = valueFrom.trim().split("-");
```

You have an array with 2 dates, then, replace each one of the dates with format `08/01/2019` to `08-01-2019`, replacing `/` with `-`, like this:

```
arrayDates = arrayDates.map( item => item.replace(/\//g, '-'));
```

Lastly, call your URL by method `window.href`. at the end the script will look like this:

```
 document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].onsubmit = (e) => 
 {
        e.preventDefault();
        let range;
        range = document.getElementById('range').value;
        let arrayDates = range.trim().split("-");
        arrayDates = arrayDates.map(item => item.trim().replace(/\//g, '-'));
        window.location.href = "https://www.webiste.co/calculate/date_interval/"+arrayDates[0]+"/"+arrayDates[0]
 }
```

Comment: I applied what you suggested no luck can you please check? One of my biggest problem is calling the url actually. https://jsfiddle.net/4vchbp8d/1/

Comment: Quite close but the url is 

https://www.webiste.co/calculate/date_interval/08-01/2019%20/08-01/2019
instead
https://www.webiste.co/calculate/date_interval/08-01-2019/08-01-2019

Comment: Exactly. Please update your answer so that I can approve.

Comment: can you please suggest why you used [0] ? If had defined an id to form would it be needed? Can you please share an updated fiddle with that? usage of [0] didn't seem quite good for me thx for your help again.

Comment: @SNaRe `document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]` retrieves an array, If there are multiple forms this line retrieves all of them, and [0] makes reference to first element that matches with the parameter. In case the form has an id you can get the element with `document.getElementById('formId')` and will be unique. here example: https://jsfiddle.net/xye60s35/